# HTML5 draggable='false' not working in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm simply trying to apply HTML5 draggable='false' attribute to some images but it's not working in Firefox browser. In Chrome working fine but on Firefox, **after selecting that image** able to drag and drop. Sample code can be seen here:

```
<div id="dnd">
    <textarea placeholder="drop here"></textarea>
    <img src="http://johnlewis.scene7.com/is/image/JohnLewis/231108668?$prod_main$" draggable='false'/>
</div>
```

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanmax/rw4tL2u2/)**

I'm having Firefox latest version: 32.0.3

Google a lot but didn't find any better solution. Is there any solution for this without using JavaScript? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately even people writing standards are not comprehending *direct logic* and are instead using *implied logic*. So it's wrongly intended as a *existential* boolean, *not* a boolean. Regardless of the value if the attribute exists it is considered true. That means `draggable="true"` (instead of `draggable="draggable"` is technically correct by definition even though a lot of people argue otherwise because language when correctly interpreted is an oversimplified version of math. In short: if you do not want the effect of the attribute *simply do not add the attribute*.

Comment: @John this is not true of the draggable attribute. It is not a boolean attribute, and draggable="false" is not truthy. Links and images are draggable by default, and require draggable="false" to interrupt that behaviour.

Comment: Strangely draggable="false" works as expected on Firefox/Mac OS but not on Firefox/Windows.

Answer (score 29):

just try this

add ondragstart="return false;" to your html element

```html
<div id="dnd">
    <textarea placeholder="drop here"></textarea>
    <img src="http://johnlewis.scene7.com/is/image/JohnLewis/231108668?$prod_main$" draggable='false' ondragstart="return false;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work any more, see James Morrison's answer.

Answer (score 17):

Update of sorts, the solution doesn't work with React, however adding the below does.

```
onDragStart={(e) => { e.preventDefault() }}
```

EDIT: returning false for ondragstart no longer works for more modern versions of Firefox (credit: Hooman Askari), in which case use the below.

```
function dragStart(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

...and on the element

```
ondragstart="dragStart(e)"
```

Comment: Your update didn't work for me in React, but this is what did (far less complicated than @Giampaolo Ferradini's update to your answer):

on the element use: `onDragStart={dragStart}`

Comment: Added `onDragStart={(e) => e.preventDefault()}` on my `<a>` element and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update of [James Morrison's update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356877/html5-draggable-false-not-working-in-firefox-browser#answer-53048959): even the newer version doesn't seem to work anymore.

I could sort out a similar issue with a check inside the `addEventListener("dragstart",...)` which you probably need to set in case you are playing with drag & drop. In my case:

```
document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
    if (event.target.parentNode.localName == 'li') {
      // console.log("In case it's inside a <li> element, prevent the drag");
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      // code taken from a Mozilla example, replace with what you need:
      // store a ref. on the dragged elem
      dragged = event.target;
      // make it half transparent
      event.target.style.opacity = .5;
    }
}, false);
```

To check for an `<img>` the check would look something like `if (event.target.localName == 'img') {...`

As per the OP request: all of the "html only" solutions I have tried were not working.

Answer (score -2):

You can set the following CSS properties to the image:

```
.unselectable {
    /* For Opera and <= IE9, we need to add unselectable="on" attribute onto each element */
    /* Check this site for more details: http://help.dottoro.com/lhwdpnva.php */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* These user-select properties are inheritable, used to prevent text selection */
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none; /* From IE10 only */
    user-select: none; /* Not valid CSS yet, as of July 2012 */

    -webkit-user-drag: none; /* Prevents dragging of images/divs etc */
    user-drag: none;
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<img src="something.jpg" class="unselectable">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rw4tL2u2/2/)

Comment: Applied as suggested CSS but still able to drag. See updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rw4tL2u2/1/)

Comment: @Sandeep: You have to add class to image. See the updated answer.

Comment: Did you check my updated Jsfiddle code? Plz see that. Already added but still not working.

Comment: That class was already added and now you added one more times.