# scrollable <div> becomes draggable when inside <a> tag

Tags: html, css

```css
.img {
    width: 200px;
 height: 150px;
 display: block;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin: 0px auto;
 background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" draggable="false">
   <div class="img" style="background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/tI5jq2c.jpg');">
      </div>
      
   <div class="caption" draggable="false" style="height: 150px;overflow: auto;">              
      <h3>
            Title
         </h3>
     <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
      </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

When i try to scroll the div by click on the scroll bar it drags. I searched and found the draggable="false" part but it works only on the image.

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Which browser are you using? On Chrome, Edge IE11 and Opera, it is working as expected. It is known not to work in Firefox, which require a JS workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356877/html5-draggable-false-not-working-in-firefox-browser

Comment: Yeah That seems pretty much it.  draggable="false" seems to work for images in Firefox though. That's what made it confusing. Thanks .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be you can use some CSS on the `<p>` element.

In [THIS LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow) they give a clear example.

I hope I helped a bit :)

Best regards,
Dimitar Georgiev