# FireFox problem on draggable div with non-draggable children image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I have set up a horizontal draggable div using the script below. In chrome everything works fine and children images are not darggable as I set `draggable='false'`.

As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356877/html5-draggable-false-not-working-in-firefox-browser) the attribute `draggable='false'` is not enough in FireFox. I have tried both old and updated answer on the above question (`ondragstart="return false"`)and both of them work on a simple image in the screen but in my case I think somewhere it is being overriden by the drag-handlig script on the parent div. I can not find where the conflict occures whether in the CSS or SCRIPT.

**note:** As you see in the script I assume the movement smaller than 8px as click event and the problem starts after 8px of movement. Actually in the Firefox after 8px of movement, The images are being cut from the parent and you can drag it everywhere in the window.

```js
function handle_mousedown(e){

    window.my_dragging = {};
    my_dragging.pageX0 = e.pageX;
    my_dragging.pageY0 = e.pageY;
    my_dragging.elem = this;
    my_dragging.offset0 = $(this).scrollLeft();

    $(".catHolder").on("click",function(e){return true;});
    
    function handle_dragging(e){
     var amount=e.pageX - my_dragging.pageX0;
        var left = my_dragging.offset0 - amount;
        
        if (Math.abs(amount)>8){
         $(".catHolder").one("click",function(e){return false;});
        }
        $(my_dragging.elem).scrollLeft(left);
    }
    
    function handle_mouseup(e){
     $(".catHolder").on("click",function(e){return true;});
        $(window).off('mousemove', handle_dragging).off('mouseup', handle_mouseup);
    }
    
    $(window).on('mouseup', handle_mouseup).on('mousemove', handle_dragging);
}

$(document).ready(function(){$(".catHolder").mousedown(handle_mousedown);})
```

```css
.catHolder{
  width:400px;
  max-width:100%;
  border:5px solid #ff8800;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.noselect{
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none; 
  user-select: none;
}

.catSquare{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catHolder">

    <div class="catSquare noselect">
      <a href="#" draggable="false">
        <table>
          <tr><td><img ondragstart="return false" draggable="false" src="https://www.codesd.com/static/img/logo.jpg"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>text</td></tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="catSquare">
      <a href="#" draggable="false">
        <table>
          <tr><td><img  ondragstart="return false" draggable="false" src="https://www.codesd.com/static/img/logo.jpg"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>text</td></tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="catSquare">
      <a href="#" draggable="false">
        <table>
          <tr><td><img  ondragstart="return false" draggable="false" src="https://www.codesd.com/static/img/logo.jpg"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>text</td></tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="catSquare">
      <a href="#" draggable="false">
        <table>
          <tr><td><img  ondragstart="return false" draggable="false" src="https://www.codesd.com/static/img/logo.jpg"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>text</td></tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </div>    
   
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the images are the children of `<a>` tag, I had to add  `ondragstart="return false"` on `<a>` tag too. In fact the `<a>` tag receives the mousdown event first and the images was being darrged with their parent anchor.

```js
function handle_mousedown(e){

    window.my_dragging = {};
    my_dragging.pageX0 = e.pageX;
    my_dragging.pageY0 = e.pageY;
    my_dragging.elem = this;
    my_dragging.offset0 = $(this).scrollLeft();

    $(".catHolder").on("click",function(e){return true;});
    
    function handle_dragging(e){
     var amount=e.pageX - my_dragging.pageX0;
        var left = my_dragging.offset0 - amount;
        
        if (Math.abs(amount)>8){
         $(".catHolder").one("click",function(e){return false;});
        }
        $(my_dragging.elem).scrollLeft(left);
    }
    
    function handle_mouseup(e){
     $(".catHolder").on("click",function(e){return true;});
        $(window).off('mousemove', handle_dragging).off('mouseup', handle_mouseup);
    }
    
    $(window).on('mouseup', handle_mouseup).on('mousemove', handle_dragging);
}

$(document).ready(function(){$(".catHolder").mousedown(handle_mousedown);})
```

```css
.catHolder{
  width:400px;
  max-width:100%;
  border:5px solid #ff8800;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.noselect{
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none; 
  user-select: none;
}

.catSquare{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catHolder">

    <div class="catSquare noselect">
      <a href="#" draggable="false" ondragstart="return false">
        <table>
          <tr><td><img ondragstart="return false" draggable="false" src="https://www.codesd.com/static/img/logo.jpg"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>text</td></tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="catSquare">
      <a href="#" draggable="false" ondragstart="return false">
        <table>
          <tr><td><img  ondragstart="return false" draggable="false" src="https://www.codesd.com/static/img/logo.jpg"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>text</td></tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="catSquare">
      <a href="#" draggable="false" ondragstart="return false">
        <table>
          <tr><td><img  ondragstart="return false" draggable="false" src="https://www.codesd.com/static/img/logo.jpg"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>text</td></tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="catSquare">
      <a href="#" draggable="false" ondragstart="return false">
        <table>
          <tr><td><img  ondragstart="return false" draggable="false" src="https://www.codesd.com/static/img/logo.jpg"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>text</td></tr>
        </table>
      </a>
    </div>    
   
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```